# How to overshadow build-in function with dynamic variables

Tags: matlab

When dynamically creating variables with `assignin` in Matlab, this does not work when the variable name conflicts with an existing function name. Here is an example:

```
function test(  )
    f()
    Beta
    beta
end

function f()
    assignin('caller','Beta',1)
    assignin('caller','beta',1)
end
```

Evaluating `beta` fails, since it is not recognized as a variable.

```
>> test

Beta =

     1

Not enough input arguments.

Error in beta (line 19)
y = exp(betaln(z,w));

Error in test (line 5)
    beta
```

Apparently this is because the initial JIT compilation recognizes function calls and does not over-shadow existing functions (in this case the `beta` function from the statistics toolbox) by dynamically created variables.

My question is whether there is a way to force overshadowing functions using `assignin`, making the above example code work.

---

PS: One way would be to initialize the variable name by adding `beta=[];` on the first line of `test()`. The problem is that in the application I am interested in, I don't know the variable names ex ante.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on line 4 and type `beta` in the command window, you get `1`, but if you _run_ the next line (F10), MATLAB calls the `beta` function and you get the error. Disabling the JIT accelerator (`feature accel off`) doesn't help. Strange.

Comment: Yes, setting a break point and evaluating `beta` bypasses the JIT compiler, so things work out as intended.

Comment: A thought. Not necessarily a good one and can't promise it will work. On line 1, try calling `eval([varname '=[]'])` and then you can pick the variable name at run time?

Comment: @chessofnerd, unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem (also I try to avoid `eval` as much as possible)

Comment: Can you concatenate another string with it? Something like:  `assignin('caller',['beta','1'],1)` (to avoid over-shadowin). Not elegant though

Comment: @SardarUsama, doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why not just use output arguments? `assignin` should really be avoided

Comment: @bob, sorry it didn't work. I'd agree use of eval should be avoided. Should assigning be avoided to?

Comment: I agree that dynamic variable generation is not good practice in general. In this case, it really simplifies my life a lot, though, and having a solution would be helpful.